# sqlite GROUP BY and ORDER

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, min, having

Is it possible to get value from column path (a string) where column status (string) is "REC", else if status="INFO", ... ?

```
SELECT status, count(idFileRemote), 
round(avg(rating), 2) AS rating, 
album, coverhash, path 
FROM tracks 
GROUP BY album
```

Ex: If I have

```
status   Album  Path
------   -----  -----
INFO     foo    path1
REC      foo    path2
OTHER    foo    path3

INFO     bar    path91
OTHER    bar    path93
```

I would get

```
status   Album  Path
REC      foo    path2
INFO     bar    path91
```

Comment: To the one who gave my question a -1, could you please tell me why so I can update it accordingly? Thanks

Comment: Your query works well with "DB Browser for SQLite" coincidentally. In a query where you `group by album` all the unaggregated column values returned: status, coverhash and  path are arbitrary. Edit your question and explain in details what you want the query to return, better with sample data and expected results.

Comment: @forpas I have updated my question. I hope it suits better the standards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize [SQLite's bare columns](https://www.sqlite.org/draft/lang_select.html#bare_columns_in_an_aggregate_query) to use conditional aggregation in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM tracks
GROUP BY Album
HAVING MIN(CASE status WHEN 'REC' THEN 1 WHEN 'INFO' THEN 2 ELSE 3 END);
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=4465a87a93d15b007a7e0a922260a52f).

Note that this problem would be typically solved with window functions, but I don't use them in my query because Android supports them only since API version 30.